# Pyspark VS native python speed

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running Spark on a Ubuntu VM (4GB, 2 cores). I am doing this simple test of a word count. I am comparing it to a simple Python `dict()` counter. I find that Pyspark is 5x slower (takes more time).

Is this because of the initialisation or do I need to tune a parameter?

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append('/home/dirk/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python')
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']='/home/dirk/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/'
os.environ['SPARK_WORKER_CORES']='2'
os.environ['SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY']='2g'

import time
import py4j
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from operator import add

conf=(SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('app'))
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)

f='big3.txt'

s=time.time()
lines=sc.textFile(f)
counts=lines.flatMap(lambda x:x.split(' ')).map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(add)
output=counts.collect()
print len(output)
for (word, count) in output:
    if count>100: print word, count
sc.stop()
print 'elapsed',time.time()-s

s=time.time()
f1=open(f,'r')
freq={}
for line in f1:
    words=line.split(' ')
    for w in words:
        if w not in freq:
            freq[w]=0
        freq[w]+=1
f1.close()
print len(freq)
for (w,c) in freq.iteritems():
    if c>100: print w,c
print 'elapsed',time.time()-s
```

Comment: There's of course a certain overhead to farming out a Spark job, vs. just continuing with straight Python code. If that overhead is larger than the actual job, you won't see any benefits. What kind of absolute runtimes are you seeing?

Comment: That sounds about as expected. Try a job which takes several hours, or at least minutes, to complete and compare. Jobs in the range of several seconds are not worth farming out to a system intended to handle ***massive*** data analysis.

Comment: besides the fact that spark uses some overhead, it could also be the fact that you're using only 2 cores. The parallelism of a program pays dividends when you have multiple cores.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, Spark isn't ideal for such short-lived jobs. You'd better run it on hundreds of files, each being at least a few megabytes in size. Even then it might saturate the HDD reading speed before the CPU gets 100% utilized, ideally you'd have at least a few computers with SSDs to get real advantage from Spark :)